# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON only in my put calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, json, stringify

So I'm making a put call:

```
const updateAPIData = (userId) => {
        axios.put(`https://localhost:44373/api/Users/${userId}`, {
            userId,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            emailAddress,
            phoneNumber,
            password
        }).then(() => {
            navigate('/ReadUser')
        })
    }
```

and I get the following response: `Converting circular structure to JSON`

I understand that this means that I'm doing something wrong when I'm sending the json object and that I need to stringify the variables. However I don't get exactly how to solve it? Should I stringify all the variables "inside" axios.put?

Below is the full code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Checkbox, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Update() {
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [emailAddress, setEmailAddress] = useState('');
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState(false);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        //createAPIEndpoint(ENDPOINTS.USERS).fetchAll()
        //    .then(res => {
        //        let userList = res.data.map(item => ({
        //            id: item.userId,
        //        }))
        //    })
        //    .catch(err => console.log(err))
        setUserId(localStorage.getItem('UserId'))
        setFirstName(localStorage.getItem('First Name'));
        setLastName(localStorage.getItem('Last Name'));
        setEmailAddress(localStorage.getItem('EmailAddress'));
        setPhoneNumber(localStorage.getItem('Phonenumber'));
        setPassword(localStorage.getItem('Password'))
    }, []);

    const updateAPIData = (userId) => {
        axios.put(`https://localhost:44373/api/Users/${userId}`, {
            userId,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            emailAddress,
            phoneNumber,
            password
        }).then(() => {
            navigate('/ReadUser')
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Form className="create-form">
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input placeholder='First Name' value={firstName} onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)} />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input placeholder='Last Name' value={lastName} onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)} />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Emailaddress</label>
                    <input placeholder='EmailAddress' value={emailAddress} onChange={(e) => setEmailAddress(e.target.value)} />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Phonenumber</label>
                    <input placeholder='Phonenumber' value={phoneNumber} onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)} />
                </Form.Field> <Form.Field>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input placeholder='Password' value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                </Form.Field>
                <Button type='submit' onClick={updateAPIData}>Update</Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

UserController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SportManagmentApi.Models;
using WebApplication6.Models;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly SportManagementDbContext _context;

        public UsersController(SportManagementDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Users
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Users>>> GetUsers()
        {
            return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Users/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Users>> GetUsers(int id)
        {
            var users = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);

            if (users == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return users;
        }

        // PUT: api/Users/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutUsers(int id, Users users)
        {
            if (id != users.UserId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(users).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!UsersExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Users
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Users>> PostUsers(Users users)
        {
            _context.Users.Add(users);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetUsers", new { id = users.UserId }, users);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Users/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUsers(int id)
        {
            var users = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);
            if (users == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Users.Remove(users);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool UsersExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Users.Any(e => e.UserId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

UserClass:

public class Users

```
 {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(20)")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Getting info, its done in another component "readUser":

```
 const setData = (data) => {
        let { userId, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, phoneNumber, password } = data;
        localStorage.setItem('UserId', userId);
        localStorage.setItem('First Name', firstName);
        localStorage.setItem('Last Name', lastName);
        localStorage.setItem('EmailAddress', emailAddress);
        localStorage.setItem('Phonenumber', phoneNumber);
        localStorage.setItem('Password', password)
    }
```

Comment: can you show the API action signature pls?

Comment: Hi thanks for helping! I'm not sure what an "api action signature" is? Do you mind explaining? :)

Comment: It means that I don't the inside code , only an action header

Comment: Hm ok I added the userController in the question. This is the full error that I get:

Comment: 'HTMLButtonElement'
    |     property '__reactFiber$p7a2pgdhtjs' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
    --- property 'stateNode' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringifySafely (defaults.js:41:1)
    at Object.transformRequest (defaults.js:76:1)
    at transform (transformData.js:18:1)
    at Object.forEach (utils.js:245:1)
    at Object.transformData (transformData.js:17:1)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:35:1)
    at Axios.request (Axios.js:108:1)
    at Axios.<computed> [as put] (Axios.js:140:1)
    at Function.wrap [as put] (bind.js:9:1)

Comment: Sorry if I missunderstand

Comment: **NB:** You appear to be storing your users' passwords in plain text. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to fix the controller route

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{

....
 
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutUser([FromBody]Users user)
        {
          var existedUser = await _context.Users.FindAsync(user.UserId);

            if (existedUser == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
          
            _context.Entry(existedUser).CurrentValues.SetValues(user);

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
              catch (ex)
            {
             return BadRequest(ex.message);
             }
    return Ok();
}
```

and javascript

```
const updateAPIData = (userId) => {
        axios.post(`https://localhost:44373/api/Users/putUser`, {
          userId:  userId,
         firstName: firstName,
          lastName  :lastName,
          emailAddress  :emailAddress,
          phoneNumber : phoneNumber,
           password: password
        }).then(() => {
            navigate('/ReadUser')
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Serge! Ill let you know how it goes. Thanks for your time and effort! :)

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Hey I still get the Converting circular structure to JSON issue. I implemented your suggestions but maybe I missed something?

Comment: @DojaCat Can you post Person class pls?

Comment: I added the userClass in my question :) Thanks so much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: @DojaCat can you try to use post instead put axios.post. and add frombody to the action.  I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm making a mistake in the "try catch" statement. Would you mind posting what the rest of the try catch statement should be? :) MY current one looks like this:       ''try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

Comment: Hi again, I updated the controller and the JS according to your instructions. However I still get the circular structure message

Comment: @DojaCat where all this stuff is defined   userId,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            emailAddress,
            phoneNumber,
            password I can not find where it is from?

Comment: I define them in a model class  "public class Users" which I put in the question and i get them in a statement ive added in the question :)

Comment: @DojaCat can you post the code, because the way you defined them causes the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241226/discussion-between-dojacat-and-serge).